# The dataframe cannot show the desired datetimes as specified

Tags: python, pandas, xlsx

I am trying to parse xlsx file which has a total of 41 columns.

3 has number, strings and dates.

Here is my sample code for parsing dates

```
import pandas as pd

dateparse = lambda dates: [pd.datetime.strptime(d, '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p') for d in dates]

df = pd.read_excel('security_sample.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1', header=0, index= False, index_col=None, parse_dates=True, date_parser=dateparse)

print df
```

But unfortunately the output is in this format for dates

```
         LastChanged
 2017-12-04 13:36:43
 2017-01-13 02:23:34
 2017-07-18 17:03:41
 2018-02-21 18:58:30
 2018-01-19 16:52:25
 2017-06-09 13:30:37
 2017-11-24 19:18:14
 2018-03-06 13:44:07
 2016-11-26 05:47:30
 2018-02-26 11:39:10
```

There is one column in xlsx which has leading whitespaces which needed to be stripped. How can I do that?

Almost all columns have empty field. So I need to handle the null values also for dates.

And I need all columns as str.

Comment: df['LastChanged'] = df['LastChanged'].dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')

This solved the problem but how to handle empty fields

Answer (score 0):

set `dtype` parameter as `str` to convert all columns into string as below:

import pandas as pd

```
df = pd.read_excel('security_sample.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1', header=0, 
                  index= False, index_col=None, parse_dates=True,   
                  date_parser=dateparse,       
                  dtype ='str')
```

Comment: Hi can you help me with another thing. I need insert a default date in the empty fields of date column in pandas dataframe

Comment: Use your default date in following code. `df['date'].fillna('2000-01-01')`